# Deploy doesn't copy app_data's subfolders

Tags: visual-studio-2008, deployment, app-data

My web project has an app_data folder with subfolders.
When I deploy my project from visual studio2008 (r-click, deploy, include app_data ticked) it only copies files from the app_data root, not it's subdirs.

Is there a way to fix this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In one your subfolders that are not deploying, right click on each file and check it's properties: Build Action and Copy to Output Directory.  Verify that the build action is set to "Content" and the Copy to Output Directory is set to "Copy Always" (or Copy if Newer).  A quick way of changing all file properties is to highlight them all and then right click to properties which will change all their values at one time.

I'll preface this answer with: I'm assuming a web deployment project is similar to a click once deployment which what I'm basing my answer on :)

Comment: Ah yes, forgot about that. Had checked for properties on the folder itself, but there are none. It's on file level..

Answer (score 0):

Just make sure the settings of the wurfl.xml.gz file property (through Property window in Visual Studio) **Build Action** is set to **Content**. This property decides how Visual Studio or tools should treat the individual project files during compilation or publishing.

Answer (score 0):

Set buid action for the files you want to publish as "Content"

There is a option checkbox during the publish if you are using VS2008

Since you are using VS2010, right click properties ->Package/Publish Web->Exlude Files App_Data Folder

[image]

[image]